# "in" condition in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there any "in" condition in Powershell similar to sql. if available please let me know the syntax on how to use it.
   My senario is i need to get a list of ids and use it in another query.

Looking for doing below

```
//Below line i veried returns values more than 1
$desktopGroupIds = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' |  select uid

Get-BrokerPrivateDesktop  -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' | Where { $desktopGroupIds.contains($_.DesktopGroupUid) } | select DesktopGroupUid
```

The 2nd query does not return value. i am sure the 2nd query can give results if i pass values one by one. i want to use may be '-in' operator if avaliable or make the above contains work.

Thanks,

Comment: the error i get is "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Contains'." so is what i needed to change is typecast the array to int which i am comparing to? if so how?

Comment: The error is fixed now. error is due to invalid syntax for contains which should be used '-contains' and not like a method. look below for my updated answer which is fix to the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-in` is a reverse `-contains` operator that's been added in PowerShell 3.0 (so dasari.. has to update to use it). With contains you use `$array -contains -element`, while in PS3.0 you can use `$element -in $array`

You seem to have a typo in `$desktopGroupIdS -c contains $_ .....`. Try this:

```
//Below line i veried returns values more than 1
$desktopGroupIds = @(Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' |  select uid)

Get-BrokerPrivateDesktop  -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' | Where { $desktopGroupIds -contains $_.DesktopGroupUid } | select DesktopGroupUid
```

Comment: thanks for the post.  typo was only in code i posted here fixed it now. -contains is there in 1.0 also i think ref(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692798.aspx) and also in 2.0 ref (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/commonly-used-comparison-operators-in-windows-powe.navId-397925.html) So think you may not be right that i need to have 3.0.

Comment: no. `-IN` is ONLY in PS3.0. `-contains` has been there forever

Comment: you are right about '-in' . ref (http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-notin.htm) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell's "in" keyword is normally used for selecting items individually in a collection object.

e.g:

```
foreach($item in $collection)
{
    #...Process some code...
}
```

If you want to use "Contains" like you have in your solution, you can cast everything in $desktopGroupIds into an array by placing the first line inside @():

e.g.

```
//Below line i veried returns values more than 1
$desktopGroupIds = @(Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' |  select uid)
Get-BrokerPrivateDesktop  -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' | Where { $desktopGroupIds.Contains($_.DesktopGroupUid) } | select DesktopGroupUid
```

**edit**

Another solution you might try is using the -match operator:

e.g:

```
$desktopGroupIds = @(Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' |  select uid)
Get-BrokerPrivateDesktop  -AdminAddress 'IPAddressgoeshere' | Where { $desktopGroupIds -match $_.DesktopGroupUid } | select DesktopGroupUid
```

Comment: The fix does not work i get error "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Contains'." for each row that executes that condition.

Comment: Is your $desktopGroupIds returning as an array correctly? check by running $desktopGroupIds.GetType() on it, it should come back as ...Base Type: System.Array

Comment: "$desktopGroupIds.GetType()" and i got back "System.Array" as base type with name as "object[]" and ispublic and isserial set to true

Comment: Hrm, try going through the available methods to make sure, in the mean time I've added an edit you could try. Have tried both methods on custom arrays on my side and they both worked.

Comment: thanks for your post. but i believe we should not use match since we are comparing IDs here. match is like like '%x%' operator (http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_conditional_operators.htm).

Comment: @malga Thanks for the followup the issue is with the syntax for contains which is as "-Contains" and is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The update code line to fix the issue is shown below

```
Get-BrokerPrivateDesktop  -AdminAddress $regionAddress | Where { $desktopGroupIds  -Contains $_.DesktopGroupUid } | select DesktopGroupUid
```

Note above the usage of "-Contains"